# Alert Prioritization - 100% Offline Production Host vs Environment Alert (100% of cab Hardware Overheating)

Tags: performance, architecture, monitoring

Out of the two alerts listed in the title, which would you prioritize fixing before the other?

I would assume the Environment Alert is more significant because the loss of physical hardware can be more damaging than production being temporarily off. The production host being 100% offline is also a major issue though.

Guess I'm having a hard time determining the loss value per minute of either of these systems being down in a vastly scaled system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both alerts are for the same environment, then "Production Down" seems like a consequence of "Hardware Overheating".

Hence the latter is probably the root cause which needs to be addressed first.

Logically, if the hardware overheats, there won't be any left to run production on. That unless you have an off-site DR system ready. In which case the alerts can be acted upon by different people simultaneously. That is, there could be a team responsible for production uptime, they would focus more on the first alert, and another team responsible for hardware, which would focus on the second alert. So it might be worthwhile to make the priorities end-user-configurable.